# AWS s3 storage "s3-bash" issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to use the s3 bash code [here](https://github.com/cosmin/s3-bash) to get and put things in S3 storage bucket.

I am running into an issue with my AWS Secret Access Key Id File in the command

```
./s3-get -k access_key_ID -s secret_access_key_ID_file /bucket_url/file
```

I keep getting this error

```
s3-get: We do not understand Amazon AWS secret keys which are not 40 bytes long. Have you included a carriage return or line feed by mistake at the end of the secret key file?
```

I know its looking for a 40 byte key file, however copying and pasting straight from my amazon IAM key ID into a file only generates a 37 byte file.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 destin destin   37 May 26 12:13 secret_key_id
```

Is there something i'm missing or doing wrong? Is there a better way retrieve files from S3 via bash?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the official AWS CLI tool?

Comment: AWS Secret key is always a 40 bytes long. Regenerate the key and use that I guess 3 bytes are missing in your key.